# Best way to ensure Java Play Framework is always running?

Tags: java, linux, playframework, process

I have Java Play Framework running as an API server on a Linux box. I run it inside a `screen` session. This works ok but is cumbersome, and if the Play process exits, or the Linux box reboots, the Play process won't restart.

What are some process managers on Linux that will monitor and automatically restart the Play process?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a play framework problem, add your start shell file to the folder /etc/init.d,it executed when linux operating system boot.

Comment: The usage of Shell scripts in /etc/init.d is the old sysv-init system and most current distributions switched to systemd.

Answer (score 0):

Start the process via systemd (should be the default process/service handling system on most distributions.)

You need to create an systemd-unit in /etc/systemd/system/ for example called mywebapp.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My WebApp

[Service]
ExecStart=your/full/path/start/commandhere

User=theusername
Environment=PATH=youcanaddvariables here

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

Refresh the unit Cache:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Start the Service with:
    systemctl start mywebapp

Enable it at Startup (more specific for the Network.target):

```
 systemctl enable mywebapp
```

Comment: More Information on systemd Units are available here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files